# Swift making IBOutlet as strong

Tags: ios, swift

IBOutlets are weak by default in Swift. I have an object in the **viewController** Created in the storyboard which is not in the view hierarchy , So I need it to be a strong reference in **ViewController** , How can I Change **@IBoutlet** property to strong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Xcode 6 beta 2, Swift does not have a way to designate strong outlets. The workaround is to connect the outlet in IB, then remove the `@IBOutlet` attribute from your source file.

Update: This has been added in Xcode 6 beta 3.

Comment: Is there some kind to trick to this? Because I've downloaded the latest beta (6.3 beta 3) but I'm still getting errors when I try to declare an IBOutlet property as strong. '@IBOutlet strong var containerView:UIView?'

Answer (score 31):

You can make an `IBOutlet` `strong` by either selecting `strong` when connecting the outlet:
[image]

Or just remove the `weak` keyword from the declaration:

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 16):

Change the name of the outlet, it might be a reserved name so you are trying to override it.

Comment: Correct in my case it's a reserved name so it's giving an error. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: in my case it was "description"

Answer (score 4):

Its now an option when creating the outlet from a drop down.

Here is why we might want to start making them strong from WWDC 2015 Session 407

http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/407

> And the last option I want to point out is the storage type, which can
>   either be strong or weak.
>
> In general you should make your outlet strong, especially if you are
>   connecting an outlet to a sub view or to a constraint that's not
>   always going to be retained by the view hierarchy.
>
> The only time you really need to make an outlet weak is if you have a
>   custom view that references something back up the view hierarchy and
>   in general that's not recommended.
>
> So I'm going to choose strong and I will click connect which will
>   generate my outlet.

Comment: Note that this is required if you want to toggle a constraint's "isActive", otherwise setting isActive = false will remove the constraint from the view, freeing it for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

The `strong` keyword is gone again and raises a syntax error in Xcode 6.1.1. It appears like outlets are now strong by default, which previously was the opposite. So simply define the outlet w/o additional declaration.

```
@IBOutlet var nameOfOutlet: type = Whatever();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for that error is because a stupid bug. For example when I initialize a UIImageView object called "imageView" in the view controller an error occurred called "cannot override strong property with weak property". 
But when I change the object name for example "pictureView", the error is gone.
Best regards...

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 6 beta 3, Swift now allows marking `@IBOutlets` as `strong`.

From the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_3_lpw27r/xcode_6_beta_3_release_notes_.pdf):

> • @IBOutlets may be explicitly marked strong to override their
>   implicitly-weak behavior. (16954464)